# Selection color imageview android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView which has a src setup as an image . Now when I click the image I want that image to be greyed out, there by implying it is pressed .

I wouldn't like to have separate images for the selected state , because it sounds like an overkill. I have many buttons and making duplicate images for all of them with just a grey overlay sounds counter-intuitive.

Is there a way in which I can show a greyed overlay over the imagebutton when the button is pressed.
?

Comment: Use StateListDrawable, posting code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of StateListDrawable and LayerDrawable

```
    private void setSelector(View view) {
        StateListDrawable drawable;
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable;
        Drawable background = view.getBackground();
        ShapeDrawable selector = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        selector.setIntrinsicHeight(v.getHeight());
        selector.setIntrinsicWidth(v.getWidth());
        selector.getPaint().setColor(<gray color>);

        drawable = new StateListDrawable();
        Drawable[] drawableArray = new Drawable[2];
        drawableArray[0] = background;
        drawableArray[1] = selector;

       layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(drawableArray);

        int[] state1 = {};
        int[] state2 = {-android.R.attr.state_pressed, -android.R.attr.state_focused};
        drawable.addState(state2, background);
        drawable.addState(state1, layerDrawable);

        v.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);     
    }
```